# ARM: understanding MSR/MRS instructions

Tags: assembly, arm

While reversing a bootloader, i have a lot of msr/mrs instructions, but i cannot find in the arm documentation the meaning of the parameters.

For example in IDA i have things like :

```
MSR             #4, c6, c0, #4, X0
```

or

```
MSR             #5, #0
```

Could someone explain how to parse these instructions and point me to the right documentation ?

Maybe there is a script or plugin to automate the process ?

Comment: Which processor are you working with ?

Comment: Sometimes IDA has problems disassembling raw ARM images due to switches to THUMB mode. Is THUMB mode relevant to you ARM version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The presence of X0 and the use of MSR to access a system register tells me that you are on 64-bit ARM / ARMv8.

The reference manual for this architecture can be found [here](https://developer.arm.com/docs/ddi0487/a/arm-architecture-reference-manual-armv8-for-armv8-a-architecture-profile)

Section C6 describes the instructions.  You can find `MSR (register)` at C6.2.131 and `MSR (immediate)` at C6.2.130. These both access system control registers.

Section D7 describes the generic ARMv8 system control registers. In D7.2.34 you can find the information that your `MSR` instruction is accessing the `HPFAR_EL2` register which contains the "Hypervisor IPA Fault Address."  (see the table at the bottom of the section that shows the values of op0/op1/CRn/Cm/op2 that correspond to this register.)

The two instructions you show above are therefore -

`MSR HPFAR_EL2, X0`

`MSR PSTATEField_SP, #0`